mariadb(or mysql) docker container use usb drive dir as volume
Following it's my test code
version: '3.8'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: test-mysql
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --log-bin=binlog --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
#      - /media/roroco/kingston64g/test-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - /tmp/test-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rpwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

docker-compose down; docker-compose up
when use volume /media/roroco/kingston64g/test-mysql, access db denied, if use /tmp/test-mysql, access db successfully, refer following output
~/Dropbox/go/cmds/draft/testnextcloud $ docker exec -it test-mysql mysql -uuser -ppwd
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
~/Dropbox/go/cmds/draft/testnextcloud $ docker exec -it test-mysql mysql -uuser -ppwd
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

So how to make mariadb(or mysql) work in usb drive
my usb drive is like, I think its type(ext4) is same with sys drive

my docker logs when use /media/roroco/kingston64g/test-mysql
~/Dropbox/go/cmds/draft/testnextcloud $ docker logs test-mysql
2024-12-12 10:23:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.20+maria~ubu2004 started.
2024-12-12 10:23:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-12-12 10:23:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.20+maria~ubu2004 started.
2024-12-12 10:23:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB heathcheck configation file missing, assuming desirable
2024-12-12 10:23:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade (mariadb-upgrade or creating healthcheck users) required, but skipped due to $MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE setting
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.20-MariaDB-ubu2004-log source revision f00711bba2cd383825d0be1867f7d7d7f641c9e4 server_uid ktsApgX4LEgDpWmLESPdR2Ed5fs= as process 1
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.20 started; log sequence number 42514; transaction id 14
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 241212 10:23:48
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-12-12 10:23:48 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.20-MariaDB-ubu2004-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2024-12-12 10:23:49 4 [Warning] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2024-12-12 10:23:50 5 [Warning] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2024-12-12 10:23:51 6 [Warning] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


I found the reason. My USB drive write speed is slow, so in first time, docker container will run /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh and I interrupt it, and next time, when docker-entrypoint.sh doesn't run
It cause my MySQL only has root user but not "user", when I manually create user in MySQL or remove volume and docker-compose down; docker-compose up, it is fixed
